Enter text in the last line of a textbox and you cannot edit previous lines
Entering text in the last line of a textbox and the previous lines cannot be edited, help.
AI issues code like this, but nothing happens
private void srvBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (srvBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        isCursorAtLastLine = srvBox.SelectionStart == srvBox.Lines.Length - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        isCursorAtLastLine = true;
    }

    if (isCursorAtLastLine == true)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}


That code is part of an event handler of the textbox. If you need to edit the content then the code needs to be modified. Perhaps you could show the actual code you are using, and what you expect it to do.

private void srvBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{if (srvBox.Text.Length > 0)
{isCursorAtLastLine = srvBox.SelectionStart == srvBox.Lines.Length - 1;}
else{isCursorAtLastLine = true;}
if (isCursorAtLastLine == true){e.Handled = false;}
else{e.Handled = true;}}
I need to make it so that the user cannot edit previous lines in a textbox, but can write in a new line

Please update your question with the properly formatted code, so it is readable.

i have updated yet

Very hard to accomplish, especially when user enters multi-line text via copy & paste. Instead I would visually split it into two text-boxes. The first multi-line, read-only and the second one single line and editable below. Much easier to handle.

I'm with Oliver on this. Example Loophole marking text and select Delete from the Contextmenu. There are many other ways to edit a textbox then a Key Press.

Reading this "AI issues code like this, but nothing happens". Have you actually tried something yourself? Or are you trying to prevent learning something accidently?

I once done this like Oliver said, but I wanted do this textbox like in cmd, but on form add buttons

The main problem withthat code is that you are comparing the SelectionStart position with the number of lines. But selection positions are based on the number of characters, not lines.

You could be on the last line but pasting text into the textbox that contains line breaks. Code in KeyPress has its flaws but any improvement will not make it safe. One way of "complex" solution would be to to derive from Textbox override the message loop method and checking a multitude of Window Messages that all might change the content of the Textbox.

I modified that code to the following which seems to work.
private void srvBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (srvBox.Text.Length > 0 && srvBox.SelectionStart == srvBox.Text.Length)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else 
    { 
        e.Handled = true; 
    }
}

However, I suspect (as others suggest), that this is not the best way to do this.

I would do this way:
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        // here the user can move with the arrow keys
        e.Handled = false;
    }else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && textBox1.SelectionStart < textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("\n")+2 && textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("\n") > -1)
    {
        // special case for backspace so the user can't delete the last line break ("\n")
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
    else if (textBox1.SelectionStart >= textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("\n") || textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("\n") == -1)
    {
        // here the user can write in the last line
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // user not allowed to change the text. The key press is "blocked"
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}

This way the user can use the arrow keys. The user can delete from anywhere in the last line.
I think it works with copy past but i did not test it for it.

You can Copy&Paste just with a mouse or another pointing device (like your finger on certain system). A key isn't necessarily involved.

In your solution i could insert a \n at the end of the last line. It would not be shown as the real used newline as almost certainly \r\n for him. After that the last line can't be edited anymore because your math doesn't fit.

I'm just trying to show what can go wrong here and there are many more things that can fail. I'm not trying to tell that this is all wrong just that @6L4cKd09 needs to decide if such a solution can be good enough for his purpose just to not use the typical proven solution of using 2 Controls one for showing and one for editing.
